# Angular2 Cannot read a query string parameter

Tags: javascript, angular, parameters

I have a query string parameter as follows in Angular2

> http://localhost:3000/home/?code=AQCW4xPL

in my app.route.ts I have the following configuration

```
 {
  path: 'home/:code',
  component: HomeComponent
 },
```

and in Home Component in the Init Method um trying to read the parameter as follows

```
    ngOnInit() {
    /*************************************** */

    var code = this._activatedRoute.snapshot.params['code'];
    console.log(code)
    }
```

but this results a null value.
What could possibly go wrong here?

Comment: You seem to be mixing up query parameters and path parameters; why is `:code` in the path?

Comment: `:code` part is resolved to `http://localhost:3000/home/AQCW4xPL` not to query param.

Comment: @jonrsharpe that how its been redirected and its the way we adding query string params in Angular2 I suppose

Comment: @A.Tim is there a way to read it ?

Comment: @Kalanamith no it isn't. Re-read the guidance; again, you're mixing up path parameters `example.com/some/id/here` with query parameters `example.com/some?id=here`. https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you need to pass it in the path, not as a query parameter(like http://localhost:3000/home/AQCW4xPL). Secondly, you need to subscribe to the route parameters observable. This way if they ever change, you're able to reload data without angular having to reload the whole route/component. Also, you shouldn't need to use the snapshot variable. I don't think you'll get updates if the parameter changes then.

```
this._activatedRoute.params.subscribe(params => {
    console.log(params['code']);
});
```

Now if you go to http://localhost:3000/home/AQCW4xPL, it should work.

Comment: Thank you , um getting this fro the facebook so I have no control over it .

Comment: Ok, instead of subscribing to the params field, you can try to subscribe to the queryParams field. That should work.